# Did the initialism AVO originate at NASA?

Tags: etymology

The initialism AVO stands for "Avoid Verbal Orders" and refers to a written document that provides direction or instruction. I think the meaning is clear from the name... someone was fed up with "he said, she said" conflict.

I think it is used a lot in defense and aerospace, especially NASA. Did NASA come up with it?

I did find that Hughes Aircraft Company used the term in 1987, as [documented in a lawsuit](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/ca-court-of-appeal/1760431.html) against the company:

> ... she told me to prepare an AVO [avoid verbal orders memorandum] to her with a rationale for the change ...

Comment: It ought to have been written down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term was in use well before NASA:

[MotorBoating](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Bh-SyOnxlNoC&pg=PA111&dq=%22avoid%20verbal%20orders%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiyw-2M-bvrAhVHVsAKHYvtDhcQ6AEwA3oECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22avoid%20verbal%20orders%22&f=false) (Magazine) Dec 1929

[image: Image of page 111]

Comment: Nice, thanks! I did a Google Book search and found a [Business Digest Weekly from 1920](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Business_Digest_Service/4rifSoJRhxUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22avoid%20verbal%20orders%22&pg=PA548&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22avoid%20verbal%20orders%22) with similar!